# How to style a MessageBox (Extended Toolkit) without app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a style for the MessageBox of the Extended Toolkit. It works fine as long as I use it in a WPF project with an app.xaml where I can set the resource in the Application.Resources.
When I want to use it in a WPF User Control library there is no app.xaml. Is there any way to use the style there? I can't use the Window.Resources, because the MessageBox is a new window itself.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when an application loads your and another control library, and both libraries contain a default Style for the MessageBox?

Comment: It should use my style ;)

Comment: But that will never happen, because the windows that the library contains will be called from an application that is not WPF.

Comment: Move the style to the control library where it obviously belongs if you use it in there...?

Comment: But the question is: where in the library should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

First I've created a static Style property that returns the style I've defined in the ResourceDictionary.

```
   public static System.Windows.Style MyMessageBoxStyle 
   { 
        get 
        {
            var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
            {
                Source = new Uri("/myApplication;component/Style/MyMessageBoxStyle.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
            };

            System.Windows.Style defaultMessageBoxStyle = (System.Windows.Style)myResourceDictionary["DefaultMessageBoxStyle"];

            return defaultMessageBoxStyle;
        } 
    }
```

Then I can apply that Style when calling the MessageBox

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("text", "title", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MyMessageBoxStyle );
```